# is it possible to apply "return" from inner function to the output function

Tags: python

In my situation I have a lot of redundant code, which I would like to move to a single function. But the point is when I call my inner function I would like to call `return` on my parent function.

```
def foo(x):
    def inner_foo(x):
        print "COOL it's %s" % x
        return
    if x == 1:
        inner_foo(x)
    else:
        print "x is not 1"
    print "THIS LINE SHOULD NOT BE PRINTED"

>>> foo(2)
x is not 1
THIS LINE SHOULD NOT BE PRINTED
>>> foo(1)
COOL it's 1
THIS LINE SHOULD NOT BE PRINTED
>>>
```

So I wanted to not print the last line when I call `foo(1)`.

To be more clear, I will give you  a piece of my code (do not pay attention to the variables and functions that do not make any sense to you). In here I actually want to make a function that will look something similar to this:

```
def ack(tup):
    storm.ack(tup)
    return
```

And this is  the code

```
 def process(self, tup):                                                     
     """                                                                     
     Process single row, do a comparison with Redis                      
     """                                                                     
     if "__tick" in tup.stream:                                              
         LOG.info("tick")                                                    
         while len(self.failed_tups) > 0:                                    
             storm.ack(self.failed_tups.pop())                               
             return                                                          

     metadata = {}                                                           
     _fields = ['path_folder', 'hash']                                       
     req = self.extract_and_convert(tup)                                     
     if req is None or not isinstance(req, dict):                            
         LOG.error("This is not a valid dictionary >>> %s", req)             
         storm.ack(tup)                                                      
         return                                                              
     if not all(field in req.keys() for field in _fields):                   
         LOG.error("Not all fields are present in %s", req)                  
         storm.ack(tup)                                                      
         return                                                              
     status = self.compare_hashes(req)                                       
     if status == PROCESSED:                                                 
         LOG.warn("Message %s was already processed in the folder %s",          
                  req['message'],                                            
                  req['path_folder'])                                        
         storm.ack(tup)                                                      
         return                                                              
     elif status == NOT_FOUND:                                               
         self.not_found_hashes.append(tup)
         return                                   
     else:                                                                   
         # status == UNPROCESSED                                             
         storm.emit([req], anchors=[tup])                                    
         storm.ack(tup)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want to just make your functions return actual values, and then print the result of the outer function in one place:

```
def foo(x):
    def inner_foo(x):
        return "COOL it's %s" % x
    if x == 1:
        return inner_foo(x)
    else:
        return "x is not 1"

    # This line will *never* be reached
    print "THIS LINE SHOULD NOT BE PRINTED"

print foo(2)
print foo(1)
```

Output:

```
x is not 1
COOL it's 1
```

The line in question will never be reached because each side of the if statement will `return` eventually. Whether your `inner_foo` is defined inside our outside `foo` doesn't matter, that's just a matter of scope.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is a closest solution to what I'm looking

Comment: @Vor, if inner could force outer to stop processing then any arbitrary function call could take over your code. This is why others are suggesting exceptions because they are meant to halt the flow of code execution and proceed down an alternate path.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this that I know of is to throw an exception, and catch it either in the outer function or the caller of that function. This is similar to how generators throw a `StopIteration` exception to stop generating any further values, despite arbitrary nesting of functions. This kind of non-local control flow is usually frowned upon, however.

For example:

```
def inner(i):
    if i < 0:
        raise MyException


def outer():
    try:
        inner(2)
        inner(3)
        inner(-1)
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Yes, that will work, but the Idea is to remove redundant code, and by doing this I will only substitute one code into another. Mean the total number of lines wouldn't change.

Comment: @Vor, I think it reduces the code because you can catch the exception once. I'll add an example.

Answer (score 1):

i dont think you can do this. The return statement of inner function will only terminate the inner function and return a value. It shouldn't affect the execution of an enclosing function. The enclosing function needs its own return, or a call of enclosing function will run until the end of the function body, and return None.
raising an exception in the inner function and then intercepting it in the enclosing function should do the trick, for the education purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just return after x==1.

```
def foo(x):
    def inner_foo(x):
        print "COOL it's %s" % x
        return
    if x == 1:
        inner_foo(x)
        return
    else:
        print "x is not 1"
    print "THIS LINE SHOULD NOT BE PRINTED"
```

Comment: well, I know I can do this, but the question is can I return from outer function, by calling inner function?

Comment: @Vor: no, this is completely impossible.

Comment: Best way to determine whether to return from an inner function would be to have it return a value, then test its return value in the outer function. Something like `def foo(x): if x==1: if(inner_foo(x)=="GET OUT OF HERE IT'S GONNA BLOW"): return` then `def inner_foo(x): print("They've set us up %s bomb" % x) return "GET OUT OF HERE IT'S GONNA BLOW"`

Comment: Also `return inner_foo(x)`